# launch4j exe cannot find jre path

Tags: java, launch4j

I would like to ship my exe with JRE. I have configured JRE path looks correctly but cannot find JRE when I try to run exe.

Folder Sutructure:

```
|- jre7(copied from my windows installation of jre)
    |-bin
    |-lib
|- jretest.exe (the output exe file)
```

Install4j xml:

```
.....
  <jre>
    <path>/jre7</path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
.....
```

What I am missing?

Comment: why create an exe to begin with?

Comment: set JRE_HOME before you launch your exe

Comment: @Stultuske sorry I don't understand what do you want to say?

Comment: @gaurav JRE_HOME settings unnecessary in this case because I bundle with JRE. Launch4j handle jre_home and other things.

Comment: @Dreamcatcher my question was: what do you need an exe for? it provides no additional functionalities or security. There are just a very few (limited) tasks an exe can be used for, that a .jar can't be used for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. I did not set "Min JRE version" property and if you do not set that property Launch4j exe could not found jre.